# Classify array element based on value

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to have same value for each same timestamps in the array.

For example, in the given timeStamp array as follows the first three and last three timestamps values are same, then replace with numeric values and increment by one.

[image]

```
numericArray = [1,1,1,2,2,2];
```

Comment: Step1 sort , 2: find duplicate in separate array ,3: replace original array with index of duplicate array +1

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, could you please illustrate with an example?

Comment: Can't today is holiday for me. Don t have system with me . Did u get it what I tried to explain you

Comment: If u find duplicate u will have two items in separate array  is 45:39 index 0 and 45:50 index 1,  now in original array find and replace 45:39 with index +1 which is 1 and replace 45:50 with index +1 which is 2

Comment: `let array = ["C", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A"]; let orderedSet = NSOrderedSet.init(array: array); let arrayInt2 = array.flatMap { return (orderedSet.index(of: $0)+1) }` Surely not optimized, but I got this.